# Can I specify a relative “data-target” for collapse accordion in Bootstrap 3 whilst retaining the “collapse others” functionality?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for an ID-free way to use Bootstrap 3's accordion. I don't want to use arbitrary unique IDs to link the opener and the collapsed area.

This first part of my question was answered for Bootstrap 2:
[Can you specify a "data-target" for Bootstrap which refers to a sibling DOM element without using an ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805825/can-you-specify-a-data-target-for-bootstrap-which-refers-to-a-sibling-dom-elem)

...so I've converted the above answer to work in Bootstrap 3 [(fiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/francisbooth/4Yq3q/3/):

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle=collapse-next]', function (e) {
  var $target = $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-collapse');
  $target.collapse('toggle');
});
```

However I also want the "close others" functionality to still work, i.e. `data-parent="#accordion"`. I don't mind this referencing the ID of the parent though as the standard accordion does in the Bootstrap 3 docs, i.e. this doesn't need to be ID-less!

**Update after fix was found**

After accepting bbone's answer below, I've updated this block to function as the question asked. [(working demo js fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/francisbooth/nTCED/3/).

```
$('.panel-collapse').collapse({toggle: false});
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle=collapse-next]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Try to close all of the collapse areas first
    var parent_id = $(this).data('parent');
    $(parent_id+' .panel-collapse').collapse('hide');

    // ...then open just the one we want
    var $target = $(this).parents('.panel').find('.panel-collapse');
    $target.collapse('toggle');
});
```

Comment: I've edited the above code block to include the answer

Comment: Your code above will open all panels if nested in another panel. (see [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/p6xxjjye/1/). You should use $(this).closest('.panel') instead of $(this).parents('.panel').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into an issue because in your example you haven't initialized the collapse functionality until you call `$(parent_id+' .panel-collapse').collapse('hide')`.

You can solve this problem by adding the following line on document ready:

```
$('.panel-collapse').collapse({toggle: false});
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTCED/2/).

Comment: Thank you. I was so very close! I hadn't tried initialising with the `{toggle: false}` option.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated this script to work with *nested* collapse panels. Here you go:

```
$(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse').collapse({toggle: false});
  $('body').on('click', '[data-toggle=collapse-next]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Try to close all of the collapse areas first
    var parent_id = $(this).data('parent');
    $(parent_id + ' > .panel > .panel-collapse').collapse('hide');

    // ...then open just the one we want
    var $target = $(this).parentsUntil('.panel-group', '.panel').children('.panel-collapse');
    $target.collapse('toggle');
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible alternative solution with knockoutJs. 
Id attribute of panel is signed later in code. Then is automatically propagated to target data attribute and Div id attribute with 'collapse_' literal.

```
<li class="panel panel-info" data-bind="with: $root.ActivityById($root.GetId($element))">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-bind="attr: { 'data-target' : '#collapse_' + Id() }" href="#test" class="collapsed">
            Header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="attr: { id : 'collapse_' + Id() }" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class=" panel-body">
            Panel body
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            Panel footer
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I hope it will be usefull for somebody...