# How is Bootstrap notified by DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

A lot of Bootstrap plugins are immediately working if some `data-*="xzy"` attributes are added (interactively).

E.g. just add `data-toggle="collapse"` to an anchor tag and [Bootstrap Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/collapse/) is present, see demo https://jsfiddle.net/4n5zrkpb/.

I want to know:

- What's the technology behind? (As far as I know they don't listen to mutation events and don't use `MutationObserver`.)
- Can I use it on my own ;-)

---

UPDATE: I don't want [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198). I originally wanted to be updated **when** new elements has been created dynamically!
But the Bootstrap way is far more easy and backward compatible: Notify only if some user interaction (e.g listen to all click events) took place.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements#answer-27373951) answer. The basic idea is to listen to all clicks on `document` and then look what was the `target` element.

Comment: @Isma Do you know the event name where `$(document).on(?)` is called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @Marcel, I think is on('click'... Look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805825/can-you-specify-a-data-target-for-bootstrap-which-refers-to-a-sibling-dom-elem#12809794

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically an observing of a click element on the document, filtered by an attribute selector with jQuery.

It's like this

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="collapse"]', doTheToggleMagic)
```

That means, every click on the document is reacted upon, but only if the source of the click event was an element with the attribute of data-toggle with a value of collapse.

So to answer your question in the title: Wordpress is not notified of DOM changes at all. Because it doesn't need to. It only reacts, if the user interacts.

Comment: Thanks, alot. The answer of @VladNeacsu is quite good. But your answer fits my needs best!

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

It uses the jQuery `.on()` function to attach to any element based on the `[data-*]` selector

**Code sample**

If you look into the source code (available on their website) https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/download/#source-files

In the `boostrap.js:1468` file you have the following chunk of code:

```
$(document).on(Event$3.CLICK_DATA_API, Selector$3.DATA_TOGGLE, function (event) {
  // preventDefault only for <a> elements (which change the URL) not inside the collapsible element
  if (event.currentTarget.tagName === 'A') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  var $trigger = $(this);
  var selector = Util.getSelectorFromElement(this);
  var selectors = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  $(selectors).each(function () {
    var $target = $(this);
    var data = $target.data(DATA_KEY$3);
    var config = data ? 'toggle' : $trigger.data();

    Collapse._jQueryInterface.call($target, config);
  });
});
```

This is only an example, but as you can see the event is attached to the document element and attaches to any dinamically loaded element using jQuery `on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Exactly. [Here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/collapse.js#L56) the OP can see that the selector is for elements with `[data-toggle="collapse"]` attribute and [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/src/collapse.js#L371) is where bootstrap bind that selector to the elements - It's just a matter of looking at the source code on github

Comment: @AlonEitan Sorry, I did look into the source but didn't find the right line. (At that moment not know to look for click events.)